# Access a field of a structure that is within the union of it

Tags: c, data-structures, unions

This program must handle data that represents the products used in the factory. It is desired that the product represents the following characteristics: Code, description unit of measure, and price; In turn, if the product is imported you want to know the origin of the product, while if it is purchased in the square you want to know the name of the provider's phone number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <winsock.h>

void clrscr();

typedef enum {IMPORTED, LOCAL} type;

typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char description [20];
    char MeasureUnit [5];
    float price;
    type discriminant;
    union
    {
        char origin [20];
        char destination [20];
        int telephone;
    } impoExpo;
} Product;

//this procedure fails
void loadProduct (Product *p)
{
    printf("\nEnter the code:");
    scanf("%d",&Product.code); //<-error: expected expression before 'Product'
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the description:");
    scanf("%s",Product.description);
    printf("Indicate the unit of measure:");
    scanf("%s",Product.MeasureUnit);
    printf("Enter the price:");
    scanf("%f",&Product.price);
    int i;
    printf("\nInsert 1 if imported");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        p->discriminant = IMPORTED;
    }
    else
    {
        p->discriminant = LOCAL;
    }
    if(p->discriminant == IMPORTED)
    {
        printf("\nEnter source: ");
        gets(p->impoExpo.origin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEnter the phone");
        scanf("%d", &p->impoExpo.telephone);
    }
}

//it is also
void showProduct (Product p)
{
    printf("\nCode: %d", p.code); //<----- error: request for member 'code' in something not a structure or union
    printf("\nDescription");
    printf("%s", p.description);
    printf("\nMeasurement unit:");
    printf("%s", p.MeasureUnit);
    printf("\nPrice:% .2f", p.price);
    printf("\nType:");
    if (p.discriminant == IMPORTED)
    {
        printf("Imported:");
        printf("\nOrigin: %s", p.impoExpo.origin);
        printf("%s", p.impoExpo.origin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Local:");
        printf("\nTelephone: %d", p.impoExpo.telephone);
    }
}

//this one also
bool areequal (Product p1, Product p2)
{
    bool equal = false;
    if ((p1.code == p2.code) && (p1.description == p2.description))
    {
        if ((p1.MeasureUnit == p2.MeasureUnit) && (p1.price == p2.price))
        {
            if (p1.discriminant == p2.discriminant)
            {
                if (p1.discriminant == IMPORTED)
                {
                    if (p1.impoExpo.origin == p2.impoExpo.origin)
                    {
                        equal = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (p1.impoExpo.telephone == p2.impoExpo.telephone)
                    {
                        equal = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return equal;
}

//this función ok
void copy (Product * const destination, const Product * const origin)
{
    destination->code = origin->code;
    (*destination->description) = (*origin->description);
    (*destination->MeasureUnit) = (*origin->MeasureUnit);
    destination->price = origin->price;
    destination->discriminant = origin->discriminant;

    if(destination->discriminant == IMPORTED)
        (*destination->impoExpo.origin) = (*origin->impoExpo.origin);
    else
        destination->impoExpo.telephone = origin->impoExpo.telephone;
}

//and the latter also
int main ()
{
    int option;
    do
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("Welcome to the program\n");
        printf("Enter an option\n");
        printf("1. Load a product\n");
        printf("2. Show product\n");
        printf("3. Check if two products are the same\n");
        printf("0. Exit");
        printf("Enter the option, and press ENTER");
        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            loadProduct(&p);
            getch();
            break;
        case 2:
            showProduct(p);
            getch();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter the name of the product 1");
            scanf("%d",&p1);
            printf("Enter the name of the product 2");
            scanf("%d",&p2);
            printf("% d",areequal (p1, p2));
            getch();
            break;
        }
    } while (option != 0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void clrscr()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
}
```

Comment: Please review basic C. the variable you pass into "loadProduct" is a pointer. you want p->code, not Product.code.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  That would provide rapid feedback to you about the many lines of codes with troubles - faster than SO.

Answer (score 0):

`Product` is a pointer, so you have to access its members using the arrow notation:

```
    scanf("%d",&p->code); //<-error: expected expression before 'Product'
```

Comment: `Product->code` will not work here.  Need an object, not a type.